# Sketch: How to align multiple objects relative to artboard or specific key object?

Tags: sketch-app, alignment

Easy to do in illustrator, but can't see an option in Sketch App 3. Anyone know?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for anyone who's still looking. Select all objects holding cmd or cntrl and set in de x and y position. This will be relative to the artboard.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not so simple in Sketch. But there is a pretty handy plugin that can be useful for you:
https://github.com/lucienlee/alignto